Efficiently retrieving conversations with unread messages via the Slack API
I want to retrieve any private conversations that have unread messages for the user of the supplied token.
I can call users.conversations?types=im which gives me a list of all the private messages the user has access to. This however is a pretty large list of stripped-down conversation objects, seemingly one for every PM the user has ever been a part of (in my instance, 54 conversations). The object has no property indicating it has unread messages or even when it last had chat activity.
{"id":"Dxxxxxx","created":1706176904,"is_archived":false,"is_im":true,"is_org_shared":true,"context_team_id":"Exxxxxx","updated":1706176904940,"is_shared":true,"user":"Uxxxxxx","is_user_deleted":false,"priority":0}

To get this I need to then call conversations.info?channel={channelId} for each one, which does then have unread_count_display.
This seems really inefficient and results in a lot of API calls. Is there a way to do this in fewer calls that I'm missing?
